# Avoid exception with C# Substring() method?

Tags: c#, string

Is there another way or a proper way to use SubString()

Here is my sample:

```
var prefix = "OKA";
Console.WriteLine($"{prefix.Substring(0, 4)}");
// Result: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.Parameter name: length
```

So to avoid this exception I must write something like this:

```
var prefix = "OKA";
Console.WriteLine($"{prefix.Substring(0, prefix.Length > 4 ? 4 : prefix.Length)}");
// Result: OKA
```

This work but become difficult to read when you need to use this trick all the time in your code.

So I there something smart I can use like

```
var prefix = "OKA";
Console.WriteLine($"{prefix:XX}");
// XX is not working
```

I also try many alternative and documentation. My conclusion is there is no better solution or I need to write my own formatter but I would like to hear it from you.

Comment: Honestly, I never understood why there's no "out of the box" method to achieve this

Answer (score 18):

you could write an extension method that does the logic for you?

```
static class SomeHelperClass
{
    public static string Truncate(this string value, int length)
        => (value != null && value.Length > length) ? value.Substring(0, length) : value;
}
```

and use

```
Console.WriteLine(prefix.Truncate(4));
```

?

Comment: or even shorter - `=> value.Substring(0, Math.Min(length, value.Length));`

Comment: @Zohar Peled, Smart

Comment: @BastienVandamme Indeed, but not mine :-) Voted as duplicate.

Comment: Also, just noticed a type - `length.Substring(0, length)` should be `value.Substring(0, length)`.

Comment: Funny, nobody come with a solution with the formatter :-)

Comment: And avoiding a null exception _"value?.Substring(0, Math.Min(length, value.Length));"_

Comment: fixed typo - thanks @ZoharPeled

Comment: fixed NRE (in a different way) - thank @PaulF

Answer (score 5):

Doesn't save many printable characters, however it looks neater

```
$"{prefix.Substring(0, Math.Min(4, prefix.Length))}"
```

Answer (score 3):

You could write an extension method so you don't have to repeat the same logic over and over again:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Prefix(this string value, int length)
    {
        if (value.Length > length)
        {
            return value;
        }

        return value.SubString(0, length);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
Console.WriteLine("OKA".Prefix(4));
```

Comment: Code is buggy, when I try this I still get an exception.